Optimizing XID management in PostgreSQL: How to avoid INSERT locks in tables?
I would like to raise a question regarding the optimal practices for managing transaction age (XID) in a PostgreSQL database.
I am currently using the method of performing VACUUM FULL operations on the oldest tables on a cyclic basis during periods of reduced activity, i.e. from 5:00 p.m. to 7:00 a.m. The goal is to keep the age of transactions below the value specified by the autovacuum_freeze_max_age parameter (200_000_000) outside of these hours, in order to prevent INSERT operations on tables that are subject to the AUTOVACUUM TO PREVENT WRAPAROUND process from being blocked.
Below I show a graph of the change in transaction age over the past 30 days. As you can see, the threshold value of 200_000_000 is practically constantly exceeded.
Can considering increasing the value of this parameter (e.g. to 400_000_000) be beneficial, or is this only a short-term solution? I have concerns that increasing the value of this parameter may only help until the age of transactions approaches the new threshold value, provided that the tool is unable to keep up with vacuuming operations during the periods from 5pm to 7am.
Please feel free to suggest any additional measures that could help optimize this process.



@LaurenzAlbe thanks for your answer. Tell me, is only VACUUM enough? Increase the parameter autovacuum_freeze_max_age?

That will only help if you delete your rows before they reach an age of 400 million transactions, so that there is nothing to freeze. I already told you to use plain VACUUM, didn't I?

'AUTOVACUUM TO PREVENT WRAPAROUND' doesn't block INSERT anyway.  (Or at least not directly.)  So it is unclear what your concern is.  Are you seeing INSERT being blocked?

@jjanes thanks for replying. I using PostgreSQL 14.6

@jjanes Maybe not so much that they block tables, but they reduce the speed of writing rows to the database. Need to increase the speed of writing to the database by eliminating AUTOVACUUM's

Is the graph that you show reflecting your current practice of VACUUM FULL, or is that graph what you had before you adopted that?

In fact, this is a mixed chart, because I was struggling with problems with the vacuum tool. Momentarily, instead of VACUUM FULL, I used VACUUM at which I will stay, as mentioned by a colleague above, and post a picture for comparison.

Rather than using VACUUM FULL, it would be better to use VACUUM FREEZE.  Although both should aggressively freeze the table it operates on, VACUUM FREEZE doesn't need to do nearly as much work to do so, and doesn't hold as strong of locks. (You say 'during periods of reduced activity' but VACUUM FULL is likely incompatible with even a reduced level of activity due to the strong locks it holds).  A plain VACUUM, on the other hand, might decide the table doesn't need freezing and so only do regular vacuuming.
It is hard to square the graph you show with your description, however.  The graph has an inverted plateau at 200,000,000.  Given your description of VACUUM FULL on the oldest tables, there is no reason for the age not to decrease below 200,000,000.  I would guess maybe the age is being held back by some tables which are exempted from your tool (either on purpose or by accident).  Maybe you can collect some snapshots of not just the age of the xid, but also which tables the oldest ages belong to.
From one your comments it sounds like the problem is not so much that things freeze entirely, but rather that autovacuum happening during the day just competes for resources and slows other activity down.  In which case it sounds like this is not tied to xid/freeze at all, but just autovacuuming in general.

I have one more question...
I would like to base everything on PostgreSQL tools. So far, I am using an external tool that performs a VACUUM on the oldest tables in the database (SELECT to retrieve the oldest tables posted below). It cleans the 100 oldest tables every 5 seconds. The effects can be seen in the picture attached above. I am going to set autovacuum_freeze_max_age an 400_000_000-500_000_000. These are values that are rather unattainable during the day (7am - 5pm), so that AUTOVACUUM TO PREVENT WRAPAROUND will not be fired. We see that the value drops to 200_000_000.

Do you think it is possible to achieve the effect as in the image below by maneuvering parameters such as autovacuum_freeze_max_age, vacuum_freeze_min_age or vacuum_freeze_table_age? Are there any other parameters that should be taken into account when planning such a procedure?

SELECT to retrieve the oldest tables posted below: SELECT c.oid AS table_id, n.nspname AS schema_name, c.relname AS table_name, age(c.relfrozenxid) AS value FROM pg_class AS c LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace WHERE c.relkind = 'r' AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') AND n.nspname NOT IN (:schemas) AND n.nspname ||'.'|| c.relname NOT IN (:tables) ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT %s

It is still unclear to me what the problem is. Is it locks (which are not specifically INSERT locks) due to aggressive vacuuming, or is it some kind of resource usage?  It might make sense to lower autovacuum_freeze_max_age at night and raise it during the day, but alas this requires a restart of the database server.  It can't be changed with just a reload.

I was asked to increase the speed of writing data to the database. From my measurements, it turned out that VACUUM has a negative effect on the write speed.
My goal is to avoid firing AUTOVACUUM TO PREVENT WRAPAROUND. I am currently using your solution in my tool, namely VACUUM FREEZE on the oldest tables in the database. The effects are visible, but I'm not sure if the lowered XID level isn't also the cause of AUTOVACUUM TO PREVENT WRAPAROUND, because so far its level is most of the time above its setting (200_000_000).

I need to avoid AUTOVACUUM TO PREVENT WRAPAROUND. I would like to do this using PostgreSQL settings/tools (vacuum_freeze_min_age, vacuum_freeze_table_age, autovacuum_freeze_max_age) to quickly bring the XID down so that it is below autovacuum_freeze_max_age.

Your query intentionally ignores tables in pg_catalog, plus ignoring some other unknown tables and unknown schemas.  That could explain why the age doesn't drop below 200,000,000, as nothing has the task of dropping it below that for those ignored tables.

Why are you focused on avoiding AUTOVACUUM TO PREVENT WRAPAROUND when your measurements identified VACUUM generally, not specifically AUTOVACUUM TO PREVENT WRAPAROUND, as being the cause of the problem?

Thanks for your answer.
You're right. Perhaps this age did not fall because certain patterns were excluded.
My goal is to reduce the number of AUTOVACUUM TO PREVENT WRAPAROUND to a minimum, because I don't want to lock the tables because of this during the intensive work of the application that writes data to the database.
